# Could not write output file Access Denied (Output file deleted)

Tags: c#

The error I get is:

Could not write to output file 'c:\Users\Toshiba\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\forTesting\forTesting\obj\Debug\forTesting.exe' -- 'Access is denied. '

Not much I write, just want to test this problem, I have searched for answers but I couldn't find any solutions for my problem. I just have this simple code:

```
namespace forTesting
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Left += 11;         
        }
    }
}
```

That's all I write, I have repaired the Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, but the problem still remains. The problem comes after I debug the program. The debug is ok but after 2 to 5 minutes the problem throws the error. I think it is something have deleted the output file or hide the output file. You all would answered me just build the output file but when this error "Access is denied" comes. I cant build the output file. I have tried to clean and rebuild the program but the rebuild also throws the error. Somethings have delete or hide my output file "forTesting.exe". I just found this problem by trying the old program I written, I open projects\bin\Debug to check the .exe file. It disappear!

Comment: Is this error occurring when running the program or when building the project? If building, then maybe your anti-virus is deleting the program because it thinks it is a virus.

Comment: @RaymondChen I have just deleted Total360 antivirus and everythings go fine ^^ Thanks

Comment: You should post an answer and accept it rather than editing the title, because now it isn't a question any more.

Comment: Hi @RaymondChen : I have just edited the question. You are the one who answered it correctly, so the credit goes to you. If you post the answer in addition to the comments, I will vote it up. Best regards,

Comment: @AlexBell: I reverted your edit, because it was invalid. If you have an answer to the question, post an answer. Defacing the question by editing to put the answer in the title is wrong. An answer belongs in the space below, where it says "Your Answer". If you want to provide one, do so there.

Comment: Go ahead and answer your own question, then accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everythings went fine now, all I find out is Antivirus (360 Total Security) delete my project execution file and the access id denied. Someone that cant find the execution file or something else, try delete your antivirus programme :D